# Excel: transfer data from one sheet to next empty row on another sheet error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to copy cells (strings) from one sheet ('Summary Document' all on row 4) to a table in the second sheet ('Worker 1', starting at B10).  I believe I have defined all elements correctly.  When I run the first time, it works.  however, it gives me a 1004 error on the second run.  I'm pretty sure it is my if/then statement that looks for the next empty line, but not sure what the issue is.

```
Dim FileName As String, FileNumber As String, RecordingPeriod As String, RecordingType As String, Auditor As String, ReviewDate As String`
Dim A1 As String, A2 As String, A3 As String, A4 As String, A5 As String, A6 As String
Worksheets("Summary Document").Select
FileName = Range("C4")
FileNumber = Range("D4")
RecordingPeriod = Range("E4")
RecordingType = Range("F4")
Auditor = Range("G4")
ReviewDate = Range("H4")
A1 = Range("J4")
A2 = Range("K4")
A3 = Range("L4")
A4 = Range("M4")
A5 = Range("N4")
A6 = Range("O4")
Worksheets("Worker 1").Select
Worksheets("Worker 1").Range("B9").Select
If Worksheets("Worker 1").Range("B9").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Worker 1").Range("B9").End(x1Down).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = FileName
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = FileNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = RecordingPeriod
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = RecordingType
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Auditor
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ReviewDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A3
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A5
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = A6
End Sub
```

Comment: the issue is this `End(x1Down)`.  The `1` should be a lowercase `L`, `End(xlDown)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also in Addition to the comment above, the code can be simplfied greatly:

```
Sub hhhhh()
Dim ows as Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim rw as long

Set ows = Worksheets("Summary Document")
Set tws = Worksheets("Worker 1")

If tws.Range("B10") <> "" Then
    rw = 10
Else
    rw = tws.Range("B9").End(xlDown).Row + 1
End If

tws.Range("B" & rw & ":G" & rw).Value = ows.Range("C4:H4").Value
tws.Range("I" & rw & ":N" & rw).Value = ows.Range("J4:O4").Value


End Sub
```

One should always avoid using the `.Select` when possible.  See [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for great options.

Comment: thank you for the quick response - works perfectly now.  The simpler code and link is also very much appreciated!!

Comment: @Senstrek if this was the correct answer please consider marking as correct by clicking the green check mark by the answer.